# Why first run of grep is several times slower than consecutive runs?

Tags: operating-system, grep, disk-io

I run this command every time I build my project from the project directory:

```
egrep -r -n --include=*.java <my regex> .
```

And I cannot understand why consecutive runs are up to 10 times faster than first one. Actually I have seen this behavior in other disk IO operations involving large directories (calculation directory size, code commits etc.).
I think that it is related to operation system's disk IO internals. Probably it is caching on some level. Can somebody point my nose in right  direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because recently accessed files are cached by the operating system.

Have a look [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/fs/filesystem.html).

Comment: Thanks. Digging that just discovered that I need SSD for my PC and "Windows Internals" book for my brain.